# proxy_ajp wildcards

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I need to setup apache so that any site.com/*ANYTHING*/servlet/*ANYTHING* goes over ajp into tomcat, but regular files will go through apache still.

I have been messing around with this to no avail

```
<LocationMatch "./*/servlet/*">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse /
</LocationMatch>
```

This works at directing everything to our tomcat insance.

```
ProxyPass      /       ajp://localhost:8009/
```

**Edit**: I can verify the regex is correct but its still not sending it to proxy ajp. I also just reverified that ProxyPass      /       ajp://localhost:8009/ still works so I know ajp is good and I know the regex is good, but why is it still not working :\

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/servlet/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P]
```

Comment: You need to match against the hostname as well as the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `mod_rewrite` for things like this, which allows you to apply a regular expression to the incoming URI. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/((kaptcha|barcode)/view/(.*))$ ajp://0.0.0.0:9019/media-webapp/$1 [P]
```

This proxies `/kaptcha/view/nnnn` to `ajp://0.0.0.0:9019/media-webapp/kaptcha/view/nnnn`. The `[P]` at the end is a flag to indicate that the request is to be proxied, not redirected.

Comment: Can I do this if I don't know what all the sites will be and where they need to goto? They deploy and remove services fairly regularly. And all I know is site.com/something/serverlet/crazyweirdcodes/ need to goto tomcat just like that.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/((*)/servlet/(.*))$ ajp://0.0.0.0:9019/$1/servlet/$2 [P]

Something like this? 
Edit: Bah its adding in stuff when i post in comments. But you get the idea

Comment: Should be something like `RewriteRule ^/(site\.com/(.+)/servlet/(.+)) ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P]` ... are you familiar with using regular expressions to match text?

Comment: yes, looks like you've got the idea

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, use `mod_jk`.  It allows you to "mount" specific directories, so that you'll have something like this:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
    JKMount       /some_context/*        ajp13
    JKMount       /another_context/*     ajp13
</IfModule>

Alias /images /some/directory/served_by_apache
```

And so on.

This would not only simplify your configs, but would also provide you with the exact functionality you require.